# PHP: How to convert textual date string to a valid date

Tags: php, date

I have a date string in this format:

```
Thu, Oct 13, 2022
```

Is there a short way to confirm it into date with format: 2022-10-13

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: See: [DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php), $strYmd = date_create('Thu, Oct 13, 2022')->format('Y-m-d');